# Automatically wrapping long pane titles in facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I want to summarize several columns using facet_wrap. I want to give several of the facet panes long titles. For example:

```
set.seed(123)

df <- 
  data.frame(
    a = sample(0:1, 20, replace = T),
    b = sample(1:4, 20, replace = T)
  )

names <- list(
  "a" = "Nice table 1",
  "b" = "Here is a really long title that I would like to wrap within the facet pane")

labeller_fun <- 
  function(variable,value){
  return(names[value])
  }

ggplot(gather(df,, factor_key = TRUE), aes(x = factor(value))) + 
geom_bar() + 
facet_wrap(~ key, scales = "free_x", as.table = TRUE, labeller = labeller_fun) + 
xlab("")
```

Here, the long title spills over and is mostly invisible. Is there a way to wrap the long text automatically in the pane title box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function `str_wrap` from `stringr` packages and add it to the return values of your "labeller_fun" function.

With the parameter `width`, you can specify the maximal size of each lines:

```r
libtrary(stringr)

names <- list(
  "a" = "Nice table 1",
  "b" = "Here is a really long title that I would like to wrap within the facet pane")

labeller_fun <- 
  function(variable,value){
    return(str_wrap(names[value], width = 30))
  }

ggplot(gather(df, factor_key = TRUE), aes(x = factor(value))) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  facet_wrap(~ key, scales = "free_x", as.table = TRUE, labeller = labeller_fun) + 
  xlab("")
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?